# How do I insert data when the primary key column is not an identity column?

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper, dapper-contrib

I'm trying to insert data using Dapper.Contrib, in a table where the primary key column is not an identity column.

The database table is created with this script:

```sql
begin transaction

create table
    dbo.Foos
    (
        Id int not null,
        Name nvarchar(max) not null
    )
go

alter table
    dbo.Foos
add constraint
    PK_Foos primary key clustered
    (
        Id
    )

go

commit
```

This is the C# class:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When inserting data like this:

```
connection.Insert(new Foo()
{
    Id = 1,
    Name = "name 1"
});
```

I get the following error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'FooDatabase.dbo.Foos'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Dapper correctly assumes, by convention, that `Id` is the primary key, but it incorrectly assumes that it is an identity column. How can I indicate that it is not an identity column?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the `ExplicitKey` attribute as per [this issue](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/issues/351).

```
public class Foo
{
    [ExplicitKey]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Note that the return value is **not** the id of the inserted item as it usually is when you call `Insert` but is instead always `0`.

Comment: Whoops! Late to the game! Thank you!